# Logging into SO on another PC has lost all my reputation

Tags: support, login

I can't log into SO via MyOpenId even though it is already logged into that on Chrome on another PC (the one I'm using now).  When I try the MyOpenId on another PC it says the endpoint cannot be found. If I log-in using Google then I have a fresh account with all my reputation and history lost from 3 years! How do I get round this issue?

I don't want to log out of this account just in case I can never get it back again!

Comment: Adding the Google login to your account would work. MyOpenId no longer exists. You need to add another login (go to your profile and click "my logins") or you may end up locked out of your account.

Answer (score 4):

Use the contact us form linked to at the bottom of every page and select the "account merge" option.

That will have the effect of adding the new openID to the original account - which will give you a back up login. Which is always a good thing in general and as MyOpenID no longer exists an essential thing in this case.